# How to list all nodes referencing a node in a tree view

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type **Company** with an entity reference field which can be referencing a content of the same type (Company), this field is also set to have multiple values.

What I want to achieve is to list all the companies referencing a company, as a recursive tree (may be only first 2-3 levels).

For Example I have 5 Companies: CompanyA, CompanyB, CompanyC, CompanyD, CompanyE. Each of them referencing one or more companies. Let's say:

**CompanyA:**

- CompanyC
- CompanyE

**CompanyB:**

- CompanyA
- CompanyD

**CompanyC:**

- CompanyA

**CompanyD:**

- CompanyB
- CompanyC
- CompanyE

**CompanyE:**

- CompanyB

If am viewing the CompanyA, I would like to have a list like:

**Companies Referencing CompanyA:**

- CompanyB

  - CompanyD
  - CompanyE
- CompanyC

  - CompanyA
  - CompanyD

I hope I was clear enough to explain my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved this with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view).

1. I have added a View, showing Content of type Company and created a
   Block with display format HTML List of fields.
2. Added a relationship **Entity Reference: Referenced Entity** `Content entity referenced from field_reference_company`
3. Added a contextual filter **Content: Nid** with the relationship
   I've just added.
4. Provided a default value **Content ID from URL** to the contextual
   filter.
5. Added the fields:

   - **Content: Nid**, excluded it from display.
   - **Content: Title**
   - **Global: View** and selected the view itself with Master Display, set as Contextual filters: `[!nid]`

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using **Relationships** and **Format->Settings->Grouping Field**.

1. Create a relationship with **Content using field_reference**, give it the admin title *referrer1*.
2. Create a relationship with **Content using field_reference**, give it the admin title *referrer2*, and specify that it uses the relationship *referrer1*.
3. Add a contextual filter for **Node id** with **Provide default value** and **Content ID from URL**.
4. Add 2 fields to the view: **Content: title** using *referrer1* and **Content:title** using *referrer2*.
5. Go to **Format->Settings** and specify **Grouping field nr 1** as *Referrer1: content title*.
6. Edit the field *Referrer1: content title* and tick **Exclude form display**.

When you enter a node id of, for instance, *Company E* in the **Preview with contextual filters** box, you should see preview results like:

```
A
 -B
 -C
D
 -B
```